# Extract text between two patterns excluding patterns

Tags: regex, text, awk, sed, grep

Consider the output of `java -jar plantuml.jar -language`:

```
;type
;26
abstract
actor

............................

;color
;147
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
............................
Wheat
White
WhiteSmoke
Yellow
YellowGreen

;EOF
```

I need to extract colors from this text without surrounding strings. I have read several articles and Q&As and did not found answer. Here i found the [most suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns) answer.

```
$ java -jar plantuml.jar -language | sed -n '/\;color/,/\n\n/{/color/!{/\n\n/!p}}'
;147
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
Azure
Beige
Bisque
....................
Teal
Thistle
Tomato
Turquoise
Violet
Wheat
White
WhiteSmoke
Yellow
YellowGreen

;EOF
```

There is a small nuance: `;147` could be any other value and `EOF` could be changed at any time to something other. I tried `sed -n '/\;color\s*\;\d*/,/\n\n/`, but it returns nothing. Please help me to achieve the next result:

```
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
Azure
Beige
Bisque
....................
Teal
Thistle
Tomato
Turquoise
Violet
Wheat
White
WhiteSmoke
Yellow
YellowGreen
```

Comment: Are those `....` lines REALLY present in your input/output? If not then get rid of them from your question. Make sure your sample input/output is something we could run a potential solution against to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It SOUNDS like all you need is:

```
awk '/^;/{if (/[[:alpha:]]/) f=(/color/?1:0); next} f'
```

Comment: nice! thank you. Can you please explain in details how does it work.

Comment: 1) What is `?1:0`, 2) what is `f`?

Comment: 1) `(/color/?1:0)` is a ternary expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). 2) `f` is a flag variable using the common abbreviation of `f`=`found`, it gets set when "color" is on the `;`-line and cleared when some other alphabetic value is on the `;`-line.

Comment: How to trim trailing line feed?

Comment: idk what that means but if you're asking how to only print non-blank lines then change the `f` at the end to `f && NF`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed to delete all lines between patterns not starting with `;`:

```
sed -n '/^;color/,/^;EOF/{/;/d;p}' file
```

To delete last blank line:

```
sed -n '/^;color/,/^;EOF/{/;/d;/^$/d;p}' file
```

or with GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^;color/,/^;EOF/{/^;\|^$/d;p}' file
```